# Cannot start SFC

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, sfc

Trying to run `sfc /scannow` on a Windows 7 Pro x64 PC and get the following error:

```
Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service.
```

Tried running `net start trustedinstaller` to fix the sfc issue but get the following errors:

```
The Windows Modules Installer service is starting..
The Windows Modules Installer service could not be started.

A system error has occurred.

System error 999 has occurred.

Error performing inpage operation.
```

The Windows Modules Installer service is set to a Manual start.

Comment: 999 = ERROR_SWAPERROR (Error performing inpage operation). So Windows can't read data from pagefile. Check your HDD for errors (SMART values, if they are fine, run chkdsk /r /f to detect and repair NTFS file system issues)

Comment: Ran the chkdsk scan on boot. Still getting the original error message "Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service" when trying to run sfc /scannow.

Comment: have you checked the SMART values with a tool kie this http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html ?

Comment: This issue has self-resolved. Chkdsk may have fixed it somehow. @magicandre1981 - please "answer" this question so that I can mark it complete.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code `999` means

> ERROR_SWAPERROR (Error performing inpage operation)

. So Windows can't read data from pagefile. Check your HDD for errors (SMART values with tools like [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html), if they are fine, run `chkdsk /r /f` to detect and repair NTFS file system issues).